# How do i read a value from a database and return it in a messagebox

Tags: c#, mysql

i'm new to coding in c# and i am trying to return idoptions 1 of app_text in my database but when i click the button nothing happens.

I have tried fixing this but i can't

```
private void conexion()
        {



            connectionString = String.Format("server=a;port=a;user id=a; password=a; database=aa; SslMode=none", server, port, user, password, database, sslM);
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);


            try
            {
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT app_text FROM options WHERE idoptions=1", connection);
                MySqlDataReader reader;


                connection.Open();
                reader = command.ExecuteReader();



                while (reader.Read())
                {
                   MessageBox.Show(reader["app_text"].ToString());
                }

                connection.Close();
            }

            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }






        }
```

Comment: A bit outside the scope of the question, but if you "don't know what to look for" you probably should re-visit some more foundational material relating to debugging in C# prior to attempting a more advanced task such as the one you've posted here.

Answer (score 0):

I would do some things differently, but this code looks at least functional, and there's only three possible outcomes:

1. An exception is thrown, in which case you see a MessageBox with the exception message.
2. It runs as expected, in which case you see a MessageBox for every row, even if the string value in the row is empty or NULL.
3. It runs correctly, but no rows match the query (the very first call to `reader.Read()` returns `false`).

Only one of those scenarios doesn't show any MessageBox at all. Are you sure there's a row matching that SQL `WHERE` condition?

---

Hmm... a day later, I realized there's a fourth possibility. If this is an ASP.Net web page, you don't see `MessageBox` windows. They sit on a hidden desktop blocking the thread.